# Import error while running JEST and riot test cases

Tags: jestjs, riot.js

when we run test, getting below error

({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import styleManager from './browser/tag/styleManager
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

import * as riot from 'riot';